# How to pass a pfimageview from one controller to another in storyboard with swift and parse.com

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue, pffile, pfimageview

I was hoping I could have some advice. I'm making a quiz app, which contains images. The quiz has 4 answer boxes with a single image view. I can download the images into the quiz via `parse.com`, however I now want to be able to click on the image which then goes to a separate view controller so you can zoom into the image in full screen. I have been able to call the `pffile` and segue it, however my app crashes when I try and `getdatainbackgroundwithblock` in the second view controller. 
How do you  think I should segue the image?

**EDIT**

Yes sorry. So the crash I was getting was an error at code=1 address=0x48, which occurred at line +55 of getdatainbackgroundwithblock.

I have pasted snipped of the code I was using below.

I used this to call the image in the first view and make it into an image in my PFImageView.

`for object : PFObject in objectsArray as! [PFObject] {
                    let image = object["Image"] as! PFFile
                    let transimage = image

```
                image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        //  self.imageView.append(finalimage!)
                        self.imageView.image = final image`
```

I then passed it to my second view controller like this.

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "ZoomImage"){

```
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! ZoomImageViewController



            detailScene.currentObject = transimage as! PFFile

        NSLog("checkone")

    }
}`
```

In my second view controller I tried to make it back into an image like this.

` if let object = currentObject {
            NSLog("(currentObject)")

```
        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        NSLog("check1")
        imageView.image = initialThumbnail
        NSLog("check2")
        NSLog("check3")

        object.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {

            (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
            NSLog("check4")
            let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            //  self.imageView.append(finalimage!)
            self.imageView.image = finalimage
            NSLog("check5")`
```

I would get an NSLog of 3, and then the code would break.  The NSLog for the currentObject also brought back a PFFile, so I believed it to be true. Where am I going wrong? And is there a better way to pass it?

Comment: provide more informations about the crash (log) and some code could help :)

Comment: Yes sorry. So the crash I was getting was an error at code=1 address=0x48, which occurred at line +55 of getdatainbackgroundwithblock.

Answer (score 1):

You were right, I didn't need getdata. I got rid of that and instead of seguing my pffile I segued the pfobject carrying the image and the text. I then called the object as a file and put it in the uiimageview. I'll post the code I used in a bit incase anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

Why you call getDataInBackgroundWithBlock in both view controllers ?
You already fetch the data in your PFFile instance so no need to call it twice. It's could be the issue.